# background image not working for local drive

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am trying to add a background image to my html page. When I use a website link, the webpage is able to load the background image. However, when I save the image to my local drive storage, the background image is unable to display in the webpage. Please help! Thanks!

```
.header {
        position: relative;
        height: 210px;
        /* background-image: url("https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800/2017/theoreticala.jpg"); */
        background-image: url("banner1.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        text-align: center;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        /* background-size: 100% 100%; */
        }
```

I have saved the background image as "banner1.jpg" in the templates folder.
[image]

Comment: Url must be from root of your website, so if your index file is in `week 10_emoji` dir, then it should be `url('te,plates/banner1.jpg')`. Open dev tools network tab and see from where browser tries to load your image

Comment: @Justinas I am seeing this error GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/templates/banner1.jpg 404 (NOT FOUND)

Comment: Relative paths in CSS are relative to the URL of the stylesheet, not the document that you are using it in.

Answer (score 0):

I see you made a mistake in linking the image, You should use the path of the directory where your image is.

Example:

```
./week 10_emoji/templates/'Image which you want to see on page'
```

In your case it's:

```
./week 10_emoji/tempaltes/banner1.jpg
```

and for best practice try not to use whitespace when naming a directory.

Comment: weirdly it is still not working after removing the whitespace

Comment: you should add the correct path in the URL of the directory where your image is